# the upper semi-continuousity of the spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-radius

Suppose we have the specrum function $\sigma :A\to \Bbb C$,$A$ is a Banach algebra,then $\sigma(x)$ is upper semi-continuous ?

We need to prove $V=\{x\in A:\sigma(x)<k\}$ is open for any $k\in \Bbb C$.For any $x\in V$,how to show that exists an open ball $U$ containing $x$ such that $U\subset V$?

Comment: What is assumed about $A$?

Comment: I think you mean $k \notin \sigma(x)$, not $\sigma(x) > k$.  And $\sigma$ should take $A$ into subsets of $\mathbb C$, not $\mathbb C$ itself.

Comment: I think what the OP means is that $V = \{ x \in A : \sigma(x) \subset k\}$ is open, where $k$ is any subset of $\mathbb{C}$, right? You are using the partial order structure of the subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ to define lower semicontinuity.

Comment: But, in that case you will need some separation between $k$ and $\sigma(x)$ to conclude. Otherwise $1 \in \{ x \in A : \sigma(x) \subset \{1,2\}\}$ will give you a counterexample.

Comment: @Adrián González-Pérez,I am a little confused about the definition of upper semicontinuous.When $f$ is a real (or extended-real) function on a topological space. If $\left\{x \;:\; f(x) < \alpha \right\}$ is open for any $\alpha$,then $f$ is upper-semicontinuous.Can we apply this definition to prove the spectrum is upper semi-continuous

Comment: Well, $\sigma(x)$ is a set, what do you mean $\sigma(x) < k$?